# Dependency Injection and Factory Pattern in Spring IoC

Tags: spring, dependency-injection

Struggling finding out question about when Spring uses FP(Factory Pattern) and when DI(Dependency Injection). That question made me failed on technical interview.

I asked chatgpt but All its answers are unclear. specifically
`MyBean myBean = (MyBean) context.getBean("myBean");`
int that case if `MyBean` does not have any other dependency, why Spring IoC still uses DI rather than FP ?